# What is two adjacent planes in a crystal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, crystals

I want to resolve the problem of the book, introduction to solid state physics, 2nd, Kittel.

the problem is

> Consider a plane $hkl$ in a crystal plane.
>
> (a) Prove that the reciprocal lattice vector $\vec{G}=h\vec{b_1}+k\vec{b_2}+l\vec{b_3}$ is perpendicular to this plane.
>
> (b) Prove that the distance between the two adjacent parallel planes of the lattice is $d(hkl) = 2\pi/|\vec{G}|$

Here, how can I express 'the two adjacent parallel planes' in Mathematical form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use traditional notations for the basis vectors of direct lattice, $\vec{a}_1, \vec{a}_2, \vec{a}_3$; and for reciprocal lattice, $\vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2, \vec{b}_3$.

A vector in direct lattice is $\vec{R} = n_1 \vec{a}_1 + n_2 \vec{a}_2 + n_3 \vec{a}_3 $, and a vector in the reciprocal lattice $\vec{G} = h \vec{b}_1 + k \vec{b}_2 + l \vec{b}_3 $. The has the relations $\vec{a}_i \cdot \vec{b}_j = 2 \pi \delta_{i,j}$.

A reciprocal lattice $\vec{G} = h \vec{b}_1 + k \vec{b}_2 + l \vec{b}_3 $ as a normal vector determines a family of plane with the follow equation:

$$
   \vec{G} \cdot \vec{r} = C \tag{1};
$$
where $C$ is a constant specifying a particular plane of the family.

For these planes to contain lattice points, the parameter $C$ has discretized values. The plane that has the lattice point $\vec{R} = n_1 \vec{a}_1 + n_2 \vec{a}_2 + n_3 \vec{a}_3 $ has its $C$ parameter equal to $C_0$

$$
  \vec{G} \cdot \vec{R} = 2\pi\{ h n_1 + k n_2 + l n_3\} = C_0 \tag{2}
$$
The sets of intergers $\{ n_1, n_2, n _3\}$ which statisfy Eq.(2) belong to the plane $C_0$.

Then you might examine in the primitive cell to see other lattice points which is not belong to the plane $C_0$, saying $\vec{R'} = n'_1 \vec{a}_1 + n'_2 \vec{a}_2 + n'_3 \vec{a}_3 $ makes the Eq.(1) to be another values $C_1$
$$
  \vec{G} \cdot \vec{R'} = 2\pi\{ h n'_1 + k n'_2 + l n'_3\} = C_1 \tag{3}
$$
When $C_0$ and $C_1$ is the closest intergers (mutiply $2\pi$), these two planes are the adjacent parallel planes. The indexes of these two plane have rather simple relation, usually one of the index $\pm 1$.