# Showing that the distance between two adjacent planes in a crystal is $d=2π/|\vec{G}|$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, crystals

The first problem of the second chapter of Kittel's *Introduction to Solid State Physics* book asks to prove that, if $(hkl)$ is a plane of a crystal, then the distance between two adjacent parallel planes of the lattice is $d(hkl) = 2\pi/|\vec{G}|$. How could it be shown?

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/608503/what-is-two-adjacent-planes-in-a-crystal

Answer (score 2):

The solution occurred to me while I was writing the question, so I answer myself. Let $\vec{R}=n_1\vec{a_1}+n_2\vec{a_2}+n_3\vec{a_3}$ be the position of a point $P$ in the plane $(hkl)$, and let $\vec{R'}=n'_1\vec{a_1}+n'_2\vec{a_2}+n'_3\vec{a_3}$ the position of a point $P'$ in an adjacent plane, with being $P'$ the closest point to $P$. A vector $\vec{G}=h\vec{b_1}+k\vec{b_2}+l\vec{b_3}$ of the reciprocal lattice is perpendicular to the plane $(hkl)$, so $\vec{G}·\vec{PP'}=|\vec{G}|d$, with $d$ the distance between these adjacent planes. On the other hand, $\vec{R'}=\vec{R}+\vec{PP'}$, so $\vec{G}·\vec{R'}=\vec{G}·\vec{R}+|\vec{G}|d$. Therefore,

$$d=\frac{\vec{G}}{|\vec{G}|}·(\vec{R'}-\vec{R})=\frac{\vec{G}}{|\vec{G}|}·\Delta\vec{R}=\frac{2\pi}{|\vec{G}|}(\Delta n_1+\Delta n_2+\Delta n_3).$$

We see that $\Delta n_1+\Delta n_2+\Delta n_3\equiv N$ must be an integer, so $d={2\pi}N/{|\vec{G}|}$. However, by definition, the distance between two planes is the smallest one, so $N=1$, and we get that

$$d(hkl)=\dfrac{2\pi}{|\vec{G}|}.$$